# Get value of <s:set> variable in radio element struts2

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, radio-button, struts-tags

Below loop runs three times, and display 3 radio button, my requirement is to check 1st radio by default.

For this I put one `<s:if>` condition and checked if iterator's index is 0, setting "true" in one "check" variable.

Now I am accessing this check variable in  either like `checked="%{check}` or `${#check}` or `#check` but desire result is not coming.

**Only last radio is coming as checked**.

Moreover, if I print "`check`" variable inside loop but outside radio like this `<s:property value="%{check}"/>`, it is displaying correct value true,false,false. But when I use this variable inside `<s:radio>`,it doesn't work properly.

Please help how to access this "check" variable in `<s:radio>` ?

```
<s:iterator value="operativeMode" var="mode" status="itStatus">
    <s:set var="check" value="false"/>
    <s:if test="#itStatus.index==0">
        <s:set var="check" value="true"/>
    </s:if> 

    <s:radio class="opmode" theme="simple" name="providerScheduleTO.contactMode"
     listValue="%{#mode.getDescription()}" list="%{#mode.getCode()}" %{check}
    />
    <br>       
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Your radio buttons have the same name. You can check only **one** radio button from the group, it is the whole point of radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are coding like if you'd using standard HTML `<input type="radio" />` tags.

When using Struts2 `<s:radio/>` tag, a list of HTML `<input type="radio" />` tags is generated through the `list` attribute, so there is no need to iterate the list and create a radiobutton for each element.

That said,

1. `class` is `cssClass`,
2. getters are accessed in OGNL without the `get` and the `()` parts,
3. you are missing the `listKey` attribute, and
4. the `checked` element must be specified through the `value` attribute.

Your whole code should be replaced by the following:

```xml
<s:radio     list = "%{operativeMode}" 
          listKey = "%{code}"
        listValue = "%{description}" 
            value = "%{operativeMode[0].code}" 
             name = "providerScheduleTO.contactMode" 
         cssClass = "opmode" 
            theme = "simple"              
/>
```

Also take a look at

- [Struts2 Radio Button Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sradio-radio-button-example/)
- [How to preselect a Radio Button value in Struts 2](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-preselect-a-radio-button-value-in-struts-2/)
- [Radio Tag in the official Struts2 documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/radio.html)

Comment: thanks, this is really the right way of using radio in struts..!!